# Имеет ли смысл добавлять хуки только на определенных страницах

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет, возник вопрос такого рода. Имеет ли смысл добавлять хуки только на определенных страницах? Если более подробно, есть некий класс, который инициализирует ряд хуков только в админ панели, есть ряд хуков который относится к профилю пользователя и списку пользователей, имеет ли смысл делать что-то вроде:

```
global $pagenow;

if ( in_array( $pagenow, ['user-edit.php', 'users.php', 'profile.php', 'admin-ajax.php'], true ) ) {
    add_filter('manage_users_columns', [$this, ...]);
    add_filter('manage_users_custom_column', [$this, ...], 10, 3);
    add_action('show_user_profile', [$this, ...]);
    add_action('edit_user_profile', [$this, ...]);
    add_action('wp_ajax_some_action', [$this, ...]);
}
```

или все же нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если используемые классом хуки срабатывают на всех страницах, а нужны только на определённых, то да - имеет смысл. Так вы уменьшите количество кода, работающего на прочих страницах.